# JS: Adding setter to parent, where has getter

Tags: javascript, oop

I have two classes `A` and `B`, when `B` extends `A`. See the following code

```js
    class A {
      constructor() {
        this.dataProxy = 1
      }
     
      get data() {
        return this.dataProxy
      }
    }
    
    class B extends A {
      constructor() {
        super()
      }
      
      set data(value) {
        this.dataProxy = value
      }
    }
    
    const classB = new B()
    classB.data = 7
    console.log(classB.data)
```

Currently `undefined` is output to the console, but I want to output `7`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Getters and  setters are not treated independently. If a subclass defines either of them, it shadows both from the parent. See the linked question for more details.